# selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium

Выбивается ошибка: `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`. При этом если вместо `send_keys` использовать `click`, то все работает и происходит клик, но почему-то `send_keys` не работает.

```
def switch_to_window(handle):
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[handle])
    
    leagues = ["england/premier-league", "england/championship"]
    for league in leagues:
        driver.get(f"https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/football/{league}/standings")
        for team in driver.find_elements("css selector", ".tableCellParticipant"):
            driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
            switch_to_window(1)
            driver.get(f"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki")
            time.sleep(3)
            search = driver.find_element("css selector", "input.vector-search-box-input").send_keys(f"фк {team.text}")
            driver.close()
            switch_to_window(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка связана не с полем ввода в Википедии, а с `team.text`. Вы вызываете метод для элемента `team` уже после того как переключились на новую вкладку с Вики, и на этой вкладке, естественно, уже нет элемента `team`. Вы можете получать `team.text` до переключения на новую вкладку и передавать в переменную, которую будете использовать на странице с Вики.

Или если вы просто хотите парсить информацию о клубах, то можете переписать цикл: сначала получить названия всех клубов, сохранить их, например, в список. И потом уже по этому списку пройтись циклом на странице Вики.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


def switch_to_window(handle):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[handle])


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
leagues = ["england/premier-league", "england/championship"]
for league in leagues:
    driver.get(f"https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/football/{league}/standings")
    for team in driver.find_elements("css selector", ".tableCellParticipant"):
        team_name = team.text  # передаем название фк в переменную
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        switch_to_window(1)
        driver.get(f"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki")
        time.sleep(3)
        search = driver.find_element("css selector",
                                     "input.vector-search-box-input"
                                     "").send_keys(
            f"фк {team_name}")
        time.sleep(3) # добавил sleep, чтобы было видно, что фк вводится
        driver.close()
        switch_to_window(0)
```